# Working with Wordpress sites

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, server

I have two WordPress sites, they have to stand separate so networked site isn't a solution.

One site at `domain.com`.

Another site at `blog.domain.com`.

They are two different sites in different locations on the same server.

So what I want to know is, is there a way to manage with htaccess or something, so when users type `domain.com/blog/article/` it will connect to `blog.domain.com/article/` behind the scenes, but the URL in the address bar stays as `domain.com/blog/article/`, so I don't miss any existing SEO rankings.

Any ideas in making it possible?

Comment: Is this your own server? Cookies might also be a problem with this setup.

Comment: not my own, its a shared one

Comment: "so I dont miss any existing SEO rankings." - can't you simply 301 redirect the old to the new? You are unlikely to be able to do this on a _shared_ server.